# User input after file input in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

First year Comp Sci student here.

I have an assignment that is asking us to make a simple game using Python, which takes an input file to create the game-world (2D grid). You're then supposed to give movement commands via user input afterwards. My program reads the input file one line at a time to create the world using:

```
def getFile():
try:
    line = input()
except EOFError:
    line = EOF
return line
```

...after which it creates a list to represent the line, with each member being a character in the line, and then creates a list containing each of these lists (amounting to a grid with row and column coordinates).

The thing is, I later need to take input in order to move the character, and I can't do this because it still wants to read the file input, and the last line from the file is an EOF character, causing an error. Specifically the "EOF when reading a line" error.

How can I get around this?

Comment: It looks like you're somehow piping the file contents to your script on standard input. If you need standard input for something else (user interaction), you probably shouldn't do that! Let the script open the file with `open` and then iterate over the lines, and you'll still be able to use `input` to read from stdin for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are reading the file directly from `stdin` -- something like:

```
python3 my_game.py < game_world.txt
```

Instead, you need to pass the file name as an argument to your program, that way `stdin` will still be connected to the console:

```
python3 my_game.py game_world.txt
```

and then `get_file` looks more like:

```
def getFile(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            return line
```

Answer (score -1):

File interaction is python3 goes like this:

```
# the open keyword opens a file in read-only mode by default
f = open("path/to/file.txt")

# read all the lines in the file and return them in a list
lines = f.readlines()

#or iterate them at the same time
for line in f:
    #now get each character from each line
    for char_in_line in line:
        #do something
#close file
f.close()
```

line terminator for the file is by default \n
If you want something else you pass it as a parameter to the open method (the newline parameter. Default=None='\n'):

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

Comment: If it's not clear what's going on in this example, you need to:

1. read your world from a file (which you open etc.)
2. build your grid
3. enter a loop where you: display the grid, get the user input, then do something with it

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.